# How to trigger an event on user is on screen lock (Ionic)?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, events

Do you know if it's possible to trigger an event in my Ionic application on user is checking his screen lock (Android device)

Example :

```
?.on('...', function() {
   console.log('I turned on my screen and I'm on screenlock!');
});
```